# I can't get my docker setup to work, what am I doing wrong

Tags: docker

I have been trying to follow this guide https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/ but it isn't providing answers to the questions I have.

I want to have a container running where I have dotnet available and being able to see the website I am going to build when I open a browser and access localhost, or any host for that matter, as long as it is working.

I created a Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install vim
```

I can build the image but I can't figure out how to make it run, access it in my terminal so that I can start developing using VIM.

I have run docker build -t mysite . and I see everthing is being setup as expected. But then what?

### Update

I can't see what I am doing differently, but I got it working.

```
docker build -t [NAME] . // Builds based the Dockfile in the same foler
docker run -it [IMAGEID]

root@4985f57eb807:/#
```

And I have access

Comment: You have to run a container based on the image you created: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/.

Comment: Yes I have been through that part as well

Comment: And `docker run` command doesn't work?

Comment: I tried "docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name some something:1" and "docker run --publish 8000:8080 --name some something:1" without detach but I still don't see how I can access the container. In my first attempt working with docker i used "docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest" which gave me what I was looking for, I was inside the docker right away and could start coding.